# Keras progress bar with fit_generator() vs. fit()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I run `fit()` the progress bar feature shows one bar per epoch, with a count of the number of samples as the bar progresses.

With `fit_generator()`, instead of samples, it appears to be showing how many "yields" have been completed instead.  Is this correct?

For example.  If I pre-make 10000 training pairs and run `fit()`, it counts to 10000.  But if I make a generator that creates 10000 samples per yield, and use 1 step_per_epoch, it will only count to one even though 10000 samples are still being used. Am I thinking about this right?  If so, what is the rationale for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bars per epoch in `fit()` is given by total number of training pairs divided by batch size. In your example of 10000 training pairs, if the batch size is 10, then number of bars displayed in one epoch will be 1000.

Whereas, in the case of `fit_generator()`, the number of bars per epoch is equal to value of `steps_per_epoch`. So if your yield is generating 10000 samples, then the steps per epoch will be 1. However, if the yield is giving 10 pairs, then you will see 1000 bars per epoch similar to `fit()`.